# Changing the color of checkbox if checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input

I am trying to change the background color and border of a checkbox but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<label for="checkbox1" class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" role="checkbox" /><span class="custom">Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox input:checked {
    border-color: red;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xv7vjspf/)**

**UPDATE:**

I can't change the markup

Comment: Checkboxes don't have a `background-color` attribute. I'd suggest reading up on custom checkboxes, as there's unfortunately a bit more involved in changing their appearance.

Comment: Interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Comment: Create your own checkbox [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/xv7vjspf/8/).

Answer (score 5):

Use below option

```
input[type="checkbox"]#checkbox1:checked + span {
      border-color: red;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: that changes the color of the text

Answer (score 2):

You will have to wrap the checkbox in a span to do it.
Found a [Fiddle with Ex.](http://jsfiddle.net/cunneen/D2mhh/2/)

```
<span class="bigcheck">
    <label class="bigcheck">Cheese
        <input type="checkbox" class="bigcheck" name="cheese" value="yes"/>
        <span class="bigcheck-target"></span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Hope it helps :)